# IIS IP Address restrictions subnet masks

Tags: .net, iis

I have the following ipv4 and ipv6 address ranges which I need to put into web.config to restrict access to them.

```
103.21.244.0/22
2400:cb00::/32
2a06:98c0::/29
```

Is this the right way? The thing I am unsure about is how to treat the subnet masks. I used https://www.tunnelsup.com/subnet-calculator/ to calculate the appropriate masks. As it's not possible to test this until my production site goes down I need to know in advance if I have done the right thing.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound" xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <clear/>
        <add ipAddress="103.21.244.0" subnetMask="255.255.252.0" allowed="true"/>
        <add ipAddress="2400:cb00::" subnetMask="FFFF:FFFF::" allowed="true"/>
        <add ipAddress="2a06:98c0::" subnetMask="FFFF:FFF8::" allowed="true"/>
      </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Every piece of documentation seems to imply that this functionality only works for IPv4 addresses (or domain names). E.g. [`<ipSecurity>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/#configuration): "These restrictions can be based on the IP version 4 address, a range of IP version 4 addresses, or a DNS domain name."

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to enter the `/xx` bits in `subnetMask`. Like so:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
            <add ipAddress="10.46.0.0" subnetMask="16" allowed="true" />
            <add ipAddress="2001:44b8:3168:9b::" subnetMask="56" allowed="true" />
        </ipSecurity>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I picked this up by entering an IPv6 address in IIS Manager, then looking at the configuration in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config`.